# RethinkDB - Multiple unique fields?

Tags: rethinkdb, nosql

I am coming from sql/django's ORM and loving rethinkdb, except for lack of "uniqueness constraints" which are absolutely crucial for my realtime app.

How to make sure two related fields are "unique together" ? The only answer I can find is 3 years old and not necessary applicable solution to my problem.

***For example:*** Users can have many "slightly customized" widgets, but just one of each color. So I need to make sure **user/widget_color combination** is unique together.

**User 1:**

- Blue widget // {'Blue widget': {size:5, valuex: 13}}
- Red widget
- Green
  widget
- -- There should be NO way this user can save another "Blue widget" --

**User 2:**

- Blue widget // {'Blue widget': {size:1, valuex: 20}}
- Red widget
- Purple widget

Do I have any option to make this work with RethinkDB ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the primary key an array of `[user, color]`, and that will only allow one document to be inserted with the same user/color pair.  Like `widgets.insert({id: ['mlucy', 'blue'], ...})`.